# Extracting values out of two columns together

Tags: r

I have the following df called data:

```
  ProbeID    SampleID ExperimID    Value    
1 2747406        1         2       6.44 
1 2747406        4         2       5.90
```

`etc....`

I am trying to extract the Value(s) in col 4 (data[,4]) that match for SampleID = 1 ( data[,2] = 1) and SampleID = 4 (data[,2]=4)

It is important that the values match the SampleID and get extracted together (i.e. for SampleID 1, value = 6.44 and for SampleID 4, value = 5.90). They can get  separated into to new df (x and y), ideally giving me x with all the SampleID 1 values and y with all the SampleID 4 values.
I am completely stuck on this, any help is much appreciated.

The goal is to get two new dataframes say x and y to look like depicted below:

With x being:

```
     SampleID    Value    
1       1        6.44 
etc..
```

and y being:

```
    SampleID     Value    
1       4        5.90
etc...
```

Comment: In your new data frame x, SampleID should be 1, not 2, according to the rest of your description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should listen to mnel but if you really want to clutter your workspace up with disjoint bits of data then do this:

```
 res1 <- dfrm[ dfrm$sampleID == 1 , c("SampleID",    "Value") ]
 res4 <- dfrm[ dfrm$sampleID == 4 , c("SampleID",    "Value") ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple fodder for `split`

```
dataBySample <- split(data, data$SampleID)
```

so `dataBySample` is a list with elements containing `data.frames` corresponding to the your required output.

---

If you really want to populate these data.frames in the global environment, then you can do the following

```
newnames <- paste0('sample', names(dataBySample))

for(i in seq_along(dataBySample)){
  assign(newnames[i], dataBySample[[i]])
}
# so now there are dataframes called sample1 and sample4
sample1
ProbeID SampleID ExperimID Value
1 2747406        1         2  6.44

sample4
ProbeID SampleID ExperimID Value
2 2747406        4         2   5.9
```

Almost anything you are doing to these data.frames will be easier to control if you keep them in the list and don't pollute the global environment with them. Especially, as in your comment it notes that you have 2405670 samples. Do you really want to create that many data.frames?

---

Comment: That separates them into one dataframe. I need them extracted into two separate df as shown above (i.e. I need all the values matching for sampleId=1 + corresponding values extracted into a new df, called x and all the SampleID=4+their values extracted into a df, called say y. Thanks!

Comment: No, @user1698774...  it actually splits them into a list whose first element is a one row data.frame and the second element is also a one row data.frame.

Comment: Sorry, you are right it does split them, I have over 2405670 rows, so only saw the first row. How do I extract them into separate df tho? Having them in one df split by rows doesn't help in regards to what I need. I am sorry, long night. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: See my edit. I don't think there are many cases where this would be particularly useful, especially if you have more than 2 million sample ids. There will be far better ways of looking at each sample individually, but without knowing what you want to do with each subset, I can't help further.

Comment: There's a saying on the r-help mailing list along the lines of "the only people who should ever use `assign()` are the people who understand why you should never use it." In particular, if there are many different values of SampleID (which seems plausible, given the large size of the data set) you'll end up with an enormous amount of clutter in your workspace. If you just want the ones corresponding to SampleID 1 and 4, I would use DWin's solution.

Comment: You are completely correct. I need a break,been awake for 16hrs straight. Thanks guys! 'stopifnot(more.coffee)'